# Migrating from Static Variables to Singleton in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, static, singleton

I'll keep the question brief because I would prefer to get the theory and implement on my own but can provide more information/code if you would prefer.

I am working on a WPF application to create a simple Expense Tracker. Right now I have one XAML page that displays an Observable Collection of an object called ExpenseEntry which in turn has four elements: EntryDate, EntryCategory, EntryAmount and EntryComment. All four, as well as a TempExpenseEntry and ExpenseList (Observable Collection) are declared an initiated in the page's ViewModel.cs using the private _variable, public variable (get;set) and the code works as I want it to allowing me to add and organize entries. I also have a float called EntryTotal which sums up all the EntryAmounts whenever a new entry is added.

Right now I would like to add another page for analysis. Ultimately there will be lots of bells and whistles but right now I would like it to just house a separate Observable Collection called CategoryList which observes/subscribes to the event in Page 1 and performs some action when a new entry is added. Specifically that action will be checking to see if a CategoryName exists. If it does, the CategoryAmount is added to the total and if not, a new entry is added to the list.

Research on the site and consulting with someone who is more knowledgeable than myself has led me to use a Singleton so both pages' View Models can see the ExpenseList. I found a tutorial on creating a Singleton instance but cannot find a guide on how to move from the public/private elements I had declared on Page 1's View Model to a Singleton where they are shared by the multiple pages. Should TempExpenseEntry and ExpenseList be instantiated in the Singleton? What about CategoryList? Are these variables to be declared in the same way in the Singleton class? Are Page 1 and Page 2 only to have instances of the Singleton? Where should Page specific methods and event subscriptions be made?

I'd really appreciate some guidance from the community on this. I'd like to poke around and get the specifics to work on my own to learn by doing but could really use a nudge in the right direction.

Hope to hear from you,

Yusif Nurizade

Answer (score -1):

Is hard for me to help you with this without some code (and I have the feeling that the code is complex so that is why you didn't post it), but anyway, what I would suggest is that you get all the static code from the `Page1`, and put it into a new class (let's call it class `A`) BUT as non static code. Now what you have to do is just make class `A` a singleton and anything will be able to access the data.

**UPDATE**

OK. Considering you comment then I would do something like this:

```
public class Singleton : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static Singleton _Instance;
    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_Instance == null)
                _Instance = new Singleton();
            return _Instance;
        }
    }

    //Dependency Property    
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PropertyA = DependencyProperty.Register("A", typeof(string), typeof(Singleton));
    public string A
    {
        get { return GetValue(PropertyA).ToString(); }
        set { SetValue(PropertyA, value); }
    }

    //Property
    private int _B;
    public int B
    {
        get { return _B; }
        set
        {
            _B = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("B");
        }
    }

    static Singleton()
    {
        Instance = new Singleton();
    }

    //INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

In this class you can now put all those private/public properties. I even inherited from `DependencyObject` in case you have some `DependencyProperties`.

Then on you XAML you can bind like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static Singleton.Instance}, Path=A}"/>
```

OR

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static Singleton.Instance}, Path=B}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I can provide the code if it would help provide a more meaningful answer. I should clarify - the current code has the variables in code as private/public get;sets no use of static. Some of these are tied to the xaml code. When I tried copy pasting them into the Singleton, the code no longer worked - is there a detail I am missing?